# ycle 2-help implementing the alt caption option on the carousel pager

Tags: jquery

Does, anyone know how to implement the cycle 2 "alt-caption" option, seen here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/caption.php, on to the carousel pager seen here; example http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/caro-pager.php

All I keep getting is the word "alt" in the alt-caption div and not the title in the alt tag.

```
<div id="galleryWrapper">
<div id="slideshow-1">

    <div id="cycle-1" class="cycle-slideshow"
    data-cycle-slides="> div"
    data-cycle-timeout="0"
    data-cycle-prev="#slideshow-1 .cycle-prev"
    data-cycle-next="#slideshow-1 .cycle-next"
    data-cycle-fx="fade"
    data-cycle-pager="#no-template-pager" 
    data-cycle-pager-template=""

    data-cycle-caption="#slideshow-1 #alt-caption"
    data-cycle-caption-template="{{alt}}"
    >
        <div><img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach1.jpg" alt="Spring" width=500 height=500></div>
        <div><img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach2.jpg" alt="yadda" width=500 height=500></div>
        <div><img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach3.jpg" alt="so what" width=500 height=500></div>
        <div><img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach4.jpg" alt="another" width=500 height=500></div>
        <div><img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach5.jpg" alt="crash" width=500 height=500></div>
        <div><img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach6.jpg" alt="landing" width=500 height=500></div>

    <div class="captionNavWrap">
        <div class="arrowLeft"> <a href="#" class="cycle-prev fa fa-chevron-left"></a> </div>
        <div class="arrowRight"> <a href="#" class="cycle-next fa fa-chevron-right"></a> </div>
        <div class="CaptionCenter">
            <div id="alt-caption" class="center"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div><!-- i added-->
    <div id="slideshow-2">
        <div id="cycle-2" class="cycle-slideshow"
    data-cycle-slides="> div"
    data-cycle-timeout="0"
    data-cycle-fx="carousel"
    data-cycle-carousel-visible="5"
    data-cycle-carousel-fluid=true
    data-allow-wrap="false"

    >
            <div><img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach1.jpg"  alt="Spring" width=100 height=100></div>
            <div><img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach2.jpg" width=100 height=100></div>
            <div><img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach3.jpg" width=100 height=100></div>
            <div><img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach4.jpg" width=100 height=100></div>
            <div><img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach5.jpg" width=100 height=100></div>
            <div><img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach6.jpg" width=100 height=100></div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is a fiddle I set up: http://jsfiddle.net/crashlanding/6s2hg8ps/5/

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, only need to make one small change given you have nested your images in div tags.

```
data-cycle-slides="> div"
```

to

```
data-cycle-slides="> div >img"
```